# Possible error with asset initialization in AFrame1.0.4 that leavs me on an infinite loading screen

Tags: html, aframe, 3d-model

Making a WebVR site, sadly whenever I try and preview the following code however I'm left on an infinite screen of the AFrame loading scene -- three white dots, a light blue background, and a dark blue bar overhead. At first I tried switching the "tree-05.obj" asset to a lower-poly one, as my initial suspicion was that the model I was using was a little too complicated to load properly in AFrame as I'm not familiar with it's abilities well yet. Sadly I still get the same error, and the code below is the only code in my site other than the AFrame 1.0.4 source script and the basic html tags.

```
   <img id="sky" src="cloudy.png">
   <img id="mountain" src="mountains.png">
   <a-asset-item id="tree-obj" src="obj/tree-05.obj"></a-asset-item>
   <a-asset-item id="tree-mtl" src="obj/tree-05.mtl"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>
<a-sky src="#sky"></a-sky>
<!--Assets!-->
<a-plane rotation="-90" color="green" scale="20 20 20"></a-plane>
<a-image src="#mountain" scale="40 40 40" position="0 5 -22"></a-image>
<a-obj-model src="#tree-obj" mtl="#tree-mtl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"></a-obj-model>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: I recommend sharing a complete example that people can run / debug and propose solution over working code. https://glitch.com/~aframe is great. Best of luck

Comment: also check for console errors

Comment: Yes. It could be you're not serving the models properly. Look at console / network errors on the console as Piotr mentioned. If you provide code it will be quick to determine if it's a problem with serving the assets.